# How to use System.out.printf

Tags: java

I tried to use `printf` but I have unexpected errors.

What is the fault on this code:

```
System.out.printf("The date is %d/%d/%d", month,day,year);
```

I want to print the date and `month`, `day` and `year` are double variables.

Comment: 1) show your errors. 2) printf has ways to deal with dates. Please check out the [java.util.Formatter API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for the details.

Comment: At least post what your "unexpected errors" are!

Comment: `%d` stands for `decimal`, not for `double`

Comment: Complete your question, with *what was the problem*, *was there any exception*, *how it is solved* and ..., so the topic will be helpful for others too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As per the [Formatter docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html), `%d` is a conversion for an integral value, which wouldn't work for doubles. You'll want to convert them to integers. Why would you represent month, day, and year as floating point numbers, anyway? You'd be much better off using a [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and using an [appropriate formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dt) for date values.

If you *must* use doubles for those values, you'll want `%f` instead of `%d`.

Answer (score 0):

Like C's sprintf, Strings may be formatted using the static method `String.format`:

```
   // Format a string containing a date.
   import java.util.Calendar;
   import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
   import static java.util.Calendar.*;

   Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(1995, MAY, 23);
   String s = String.format("Duke's Birthday: %1$tm %1$te,%1$tY", c);
   // -> s == "Duke's Birthday: May 23, 1995"
```

Answer (score -2):

Corrected code

```
 System.out.printf("The date is %f/%f/%f", month,day,year);
```

Comment: What does a date of 10.5/3.14159265/2019.99 mean anyway?

Comment: Do not be harsh, I was writing code for about 3-4 months by this time.

Comment: Boy, this answer and comment are a blast from the distant past!

Comment: I was just checking my history in StackOverflow and came across that! 