# Java printf statement giving errors

Tags: java, eclipse, printf, println

I'm using Eclipse on an a homework assignment and I'm really struggling. The goal is to write a payroll program that has a user enter their name, hours worked, pay rate, federal and state tax withheld, and then outputs the calculated information of their amounts withheld as well as their net pay.

I used what I was familiar with which is `println` statements to show the output but the teacher wants us to use the `System.out.printf` function and I can't get it to work at all. If I use `println` statements all the values fill but for some reason I can't manage to get the `printf` to do the same. What am I missing? If I use the `printf` function it gives me the error of

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method printf(Locale, String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String)
at Payrolls.main(Payrolls.java:31)"
```

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Payrolls
{
   public static void main(String []args)
   {


   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.print("Enter employee first name: ");
   String employeeFirst = input.nextLine();

   System.out.print("Enter employee last name: ");
   String employeeLast = input.nextLine();

   System.out.print("Enter number of hours worked this week: ");
   int hoursWorked = input.nextInt();

   System.out.print("Enter hourly pay rate of the employee: ");
   double payRate = input.nextDouble();

   System.out.print("Enter federal tax withholding rate: ");
   double fedTax = input.nextDouble();

   System.out.print("Enter state tax withholding rate: ");
   double stateTax = input.nextDouble();

   System.out.println(" ");
   System.out.println(" ");
   //System.out.printf("%-20s %s\n", employeeFirst, employeeLast);
   System.out.println("Name: " + employeeFirst +" " +employeeLast);

   System.out.println("Hours Worked:" + hoursWorked);

   System.out.println("Pay Rate:" + payRate);



   double grossPay;
   grossPay = payRate * hoursWorked;

   System.out.println("Gross Pay:" + grossPay);

   double deductions;
   deductions = grossPay * fedTax;

   System.out.println("\tDeductions:");
   System.out.println("\t\tFederal Witholding %: $" +  deductions);

   double statTax;
   statTax = grossPay * stateTax;

   System.out.println("\t\tState Witholding %: $" +  statTax);

   double totalDeduction;
   totalDeduction = deductions + statTax;

   System.out.println("\t\tTotal Deduction: $" + totalDeduction);


   double netPay;
   netPay = grossPay - totalDeduction;

   System.out.println("Net Pay:" + netPay);
   }
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me (JDK8, IntelliJ, F24). What JDK and/or IDE are you using?

Comment: which version of java do you use ?

Comment: Look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008466/how-to-use-system-out-printf)

Comment: As far as I know, I'm using the latest version. I'm using Eclipse as the teacher demands we use it.

Comment: I managed to get the exact same error by using Java 1.4. Maybe you should check that you are not using this version.

Comment: Also check this and make sure you were using the latest jdk version. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588537/how-to-change-jdk-version-for-an-eclipse-project

Comment: could you please provide a sniped where you actually use printf instead of println since printf expects other paramters

Answer (score 0):

- Printf methode is available from java version 1.5. Make sure that your jdk version is greater than or equal to 1.5.
- Your error tells you that the first argument of the printf method must be a Locale type see an exmaple [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/printstream_printf_locale.htm)

Comment: But the first argument to `printf` does NOT have to be a `Locale`.  There are two `printf` methods - one where the first argument is a `Locale` and another where it's a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you're using a JDK 1.5 or above, as varargs and more specifically `printf` was added in that release. It is not sufficient to just compile with JDK 1.5, you'll also need to run your program using JRE 1.5+.

Additionally, see the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) for `printf`: one requires a `String` as its first parameter, the other requires a `Locale` instance.

Calling it like the following:

`System.out.printf("%s\n", employeeFirst, employeeLast);`

should work (which is what you're commented code does).

Comment: Unless I'm crazy (Which is a possibility given how mad I've been driven by a simple statement not working) I'm using JDK 1.8 I know I downloaded eclipse and the JDK back in late august when the semester started.

Comment: Check with `javac -version` and `java -version`. Confirm (if you're building & runing through eclipse) that its Compiler configuration is set to *build* and thus *target* JDK 8.

Comment: @atc I believe that last comment of yours is the correct answer.  OP appears to be **compiling** with JDK 1.5 or better, but **running** with JDK 1.4.