# How do I make a connection for x1 and y1?

Tags: java

This is the question I was given:

> Create class (or classes) contain method to calculate the distance between two points `(x1, y1)` and
>   `(x2, y2)` which are the data fields of the class. All numbers and return values should be of type
>   double. Incorporate in class the methods that enable the user to enter the coordinates of the points.
>   Test this class with client program DistanceTest.

But I am testing with using the formula of `x1 + y1` instead of using the formula of finding (distance).

I want to use get and set method to do addition maths.

This is my code for distance1 :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class distance1 {

    private double result;

    public void credit(double x1,double y1)
    {
        result = x1 + y1;
    }
    public double getResult(){
        return result;
    }
}
```

And this is the code for distance1Test

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class distancetest1 {

    public static void main(String[]args){

        distance1 x1 = new distance1();
        distance1 y1 = new distance1();
        distance1 r  = new distance1();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double number;

        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        number = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        number = input.nextInt();

        System.out.printf("Result is: ", r.getResult());
    }
}
```

Comment: *But I am testing with using the formula of x1 + y1 instead of using the formula of finding (distance).* why? What is your question?

Comment: ya , the question told me to use distance = Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2));. but I am just testing , so I decided to do addition method first.

Comment: What is the problem ??

Comment: You should call ´credit´ somewhere before calling ´getResult´ otherwise the result will always be zero.

Comment: the problem is I want to use get set method to do addition method , but I don't know how to make the (result = x1+y1) in (distance1) connect to the (distancetest1). For example : in distancetest1 , It allows me to enter two number , but after I entered the number , the result is (nothing). I expected the (result) is the sum of the two entered number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you forgot to call the `credit function` to do the addition, and secondly you need to change the `System.out.printf("Result is: ", r.getResult());` to

```
System.out.println("Result is: "+ r.getResult());
```

see how to use printf in java: [How to use System.out.printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008466/how-to-use-system-out-printf)

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    double x1,y1;
    distance1 r  = new distance1();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    x1 = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    y1 = input.nextInt();

    r.credit(x1, y1);
    System.out.println("Result is: "+ r.getResult());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jaca classes must have an uppercase first letter

```
public class Dimension{
  private int x1;
  ...
  // Use a constructor no initialize
  Dimension(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2){
     this.x1 = x1;
     ...
  }

  public double getDistance(){
     return Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2));
  }
}
```

Test using:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Dimension d = new Dimension(1,10,40,30);
    System.out.print(d.getDistance());
}
```

Comment: Many things does compile but it's a matter of "I can't do that"

Comment: Just wondering why you negativeted. Your code above is all wrong. You trying to set something that you don't need. I'm trying help with an elegant solution but ok. Keep doing wrong it's up to you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the method main of your class distancetest1, you should :

1. retrieve the two number inputs in two different variables "x" and "y" of type Double
2. instantiate only one distance1 object "r" (x1 and y1 are useless in your try)
3. call the method r.credit(...) by passing it your two variables as arguments
4. display the result with the method r.getResult()